# What is TypeError: mime.lookup is not a function in Supertest?

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

I just upgraded to node 14.15.4, and now any supertest post request with send is failing with the error "TypeError: mime.lookup is not a function".

```
    it("Should be able to select an address", () => {
        return request(app).post(`/admin/machines/${newmachine._id}/assignments/add`)
        .send({userid: testuser._id.toString()})
        .expect(302)
        .then( (res) => {
            expect(res.headers.location).to.include(`/admin/machines/${newmachine._id}`);
        });
    });
```

I get error:

```
       Should be able to select an address:
     TypeError: mime.lookup is not a function
      at Test.Request.type (node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:265:38)
      at Test.RequestBase.send (node_modules/supertest/node_modules/superagent/lib/request-base.js:575:21)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/routes/admin/machines.js:275:10)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
```

If however I use "field" instead of send, the error goes away:

```
        return request(app).post(`/admin/machines/${newmachine._id}/assignments/add`)
        .field('userid',testuser._id.toString())
        .expect(302)
        .then( (res) => {
            expect(res.headers.location).to.include(`/admin/machines/${newmachine._id}`);
        });
    });
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, or a fix at least. If I add:

```
.set('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

the error goes away. So to update the original code above:

```
it("Should be able to select an address", () => {
    return request(app).post(`/admin/machines/${newmachine._id}/assignments/add`)
    .set('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    .send({userid: testuser._id.toString()})
    .expect(302)
    .then( (res) => {
        expect(res.headers.location).to.include(`/admin/machines/${newmachine._id}`);
    });
});
```

Although pedantically speaking, this is not necessarily an accurate test as the form type is changed to 'x-www-form-urlencoded' but considering that node.js implementations solidly can support any form type interchangeably, it's probably fine for all testing purposes.